# Property "data" is incompatible with index signature

Tags: data-binding, markdown, incompatibletypeerror

I am trying to use markdown which is giving data binding error. The datatype of [data] in my markdownComponent.d.ts file is 'string |undefined|null' but still gives error " Can't bind to 'data' since it isn't a known property of 'markdown'."

[error in ecmp of markdown.component.d.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKopt.png)

[error: Can't bind to 'data' since it isn't a known property of 'markdown'.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piEyP.png)

[error in markdownComponent.d.ts file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUTc2.png)

[markdownContent is of type string and initialized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dW11J.png)

I dont understand the problem ... data and markdownContent both are of type: string then why markdownContent can not be assigned to [data]? i've imported all required modules i.e. FormsModule , ReactiveModule, ngx-markdown ...also while running command 'npm i --force ngx-markdown' i got an error that "marked" does not exist so i installed "marked" and imported it in markdownComponent.d.ts the "marked" error was resolved but still im getting error in ecmp .

I want to assign [data]="markdownContent"

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue while trying to use `ngx-markdown@16.0.0` with angular 15

Downgrading to `ngx-markdown@15.1.2` fixed it